# Question on my proof of unboundedness of sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I want to show that the sequence
$$
 a_{n+1} = \sqrt{ 1 + a_n^2 }
$$
is strictly monotone increasing but not bounded.

That it is strictly increasing is simple I think, just $a_n = \sqrt{a_n^2} < \sqrt{1 + a_n^2}$ and using that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is strictly increasing.

For unbounded, I used
$$
 a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+a_n^2} = \sqrt{1 + (1+a_{n-1})} = \ldots = \sqrt{n + a_1^2}.
$$
And it follows because $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is unbounded. Is this right, is there any more formal method to proof this, by showing more directly that there could be no upper bound?

Comment: What about to show that $a_n^2$ is unbounded?

Comment: Guess this yields the same manipulations as I did...

Comment: To be more formal, use induction and show that $a_n \ge \sqrt{n}$ for all $n$.

Comment: You could use the fact that since monotone,  if bounded there would be a limit, satisfying the interesting equation $x=\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: does this mean $x= \infty $ ?

Comment: Well, one does not handle the symbol $\infty$ in that way.  **If** the sequence $(a_n)$ was bounded, it would have a limit $a$. Here $a$ is an ordinary number. Then we would have $a^2=a^2+1$, and therefore $0=1$, which is false.  This contradiction shows the sequence cannot be bounded. Of course from $a_{n+1}^2=a+a_n^2$, it is trivial to prove unbounded. I mentioned the (correct) $x^2=1+x^2$ approach as a fun alternative.

Comment: @Stefan, the idea is the same, but from $a_{n + 1}^2 = a_n^2 + 1$ with $a_0 > 0$ the unboundedness follows inmediately. In fact, $a_n^2 = a_0^2 + n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Define $b_n:=a_n^2$; then for each $n$, $b_{n+1}=1+b_n$, and by induction, it follows that $b_n=b_0+n$, which proves that $\{b_n\}$ is not bounded. Hence $\{a_n\}$ cannot be bounded.